# What should be used instead of sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler?

Tags: java

import sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler causes the following warning:

> sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler is
>   Sun proprietary API and may be removed
>   in a future release

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no replacement. You have these options:

1. Use it and fix the problem if the API is ever removed (which won't happen in the next two years, at least). The most dangerous option but the most simple to implement.
2. Copy the code into a new class/package in your project to make sure it doesn't go away. Most safe, pretty easy to implement but you don't get bug fixes and classes in the runtime will still use the old handler.
3. Write your own extension of `URLStreamHandler`. Most work, least return of investment, high likelihood of bugs, most dangerous.

Rationale: This is a *warning*. Warning means: You *may* run into trouble if you do this. Use your common sense to decide.